# Create arrays with different Names

Tags: nsarray, nsmutablestring

i want to create arrays with different *names (the text out of a textField should be the name of the array) when an `IBAction` function is called. How do i get the text out of the text field and make it the *name of the array?

```
- (IBAction)createButton:(id)sender {
    NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [string setString:[textField text]];
    NSMutableArray *string = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a NSDictionary and use the string as key, and array as value.

Answer (score 0):

try this . . .

```
- (IBAction)createButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *string = [textField text];

    NSMutableArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
}
```

if names are separated by space , then provide space , if they are separated by comma ',' then

```
// NSMutableArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```